# jQuery - toggle "checked" and class of external element

Tags: jquery

First: I'm not really good at javascript and I want to use jQuery functions.

This should happen:

- `input[type="radio"].select-editor` - if is checked, should hide the `#alt-box` show only the `#editor-box`.
- `input[type="radio"].select-alt-a`, `input[type="radio"].select-alt-b` and `input[type="radio"].select-alt-c` - if is checked, should hide the `#editor-box` and show the `#alt-box`.
- `input[type="radio"].select-alt-a` - if is checked, should show the `#alt-a` inside `#alt-box` and hide the other divs inside the `#alt-box`

If one of the radio buttons gets clicked, it should get `checked="checked"` and the other ones should loose the attribute.

*I don't mind if the function uses `hide()` or adds the class of `.hidden` to the elements.*

```
<!-- here's where the action happens -->
<div id="select-container">
    <input type="radio" class="select-editor" checked="checked" />
    <input type="radio" class="select-alt-a" />
    <input type="radio" class="select-alt-b" />
    <input type="radio" class="select-alt-c" />
</div>

<div id="editor-box">
    <!-- my text editor -->
</div>

<div id="alt-box">
    <div id="alt-a">
        <!-- some content -->
    </div>
    <div id="alt-b">
        <!-- some content -->
    </div>
    <div id="alt-c">
        <!-- some content -->
    </div>
</div>
```

The following is likely to be nonsense. I hope someone can tell me how to handle this...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( document ).ready( function($)
        {
            $( "#select container input[type=\"radio\"]" ).click( function()
            {
                // something should happen here
            } );
        }
    );
</script>
```

This is driving me crazy, so thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just give them all the same `name`, the user-agent will automatically allow selection of only one radio button in the 'group'; selecting one will deselect any other that might have been selected:

```
<div id="select-container">
    <input type="radio" name="selector" class="select-editor" checked="checked" />
    <input type="radio" name="selector" class="select-alt-a" />
    <input type="radio" name="selector" class="select-alt-b" />
    <input type="radio" name="selector" class="select-alt-c" />
</div>
```

To do something on selection of a radio button you could hook into the `change` event:

```
$('#select-container input[type="radio"]').change(function() {
     //check the id of this and trigger the appropriate action
 });
```